# Trying to create a list that is separated by colons and remove it

Tags: bash

I am trying to setup a script that uses the cat function to create File with Perl:PHP:C++:Python:COBOL:Ruby:Rails

What i am trying to do it take this colon-separated list and output the items, one per line, to standard output (without colons)

```
#!/bin/bash
cat File
Perl:PHP:C++:Python:COBOL:Ruby:Rails
split (/:/)
```

I keep getting errors i'm probably just not using the split command properly

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `split` for this. `split` is a tool for breaking up a file into smaller files based on a size threshold. It's not for breaking on a delimiter. But if you just want to output to standard output, here's a quick way:

```
$ cat > foo # Write one line to the new file `foo`
Perl:PHP:C++:Python:COBOL:Ruby:Rails 
$ IFS=: read -a langs < foo # Read the 1st line of the file into the array `langs`
                            # splitting on colon
$ printf '%s\n' "${langs[@]}" # Wordsplit the array into arguments to `printf`
Perl
PHP
C++
Python
COBOL
Ruby
Rails
```

You could as easily just read the entire file with `$(<foo)`, but then you have to do some more sophisticated delimiter juggling:

```
$ splitByColon() { # Use a function to maintain scope
>   local IFS=: # Set the colon as the field separator just in this function
>   local -a langs=( $(<"$1") ) # Read the file into the array, split on colons
>   IFS=$'\n' # Prepare to output split by newlines 
>   echo "${langs[*]}"
> }
$ splitByColon foo
```

Comment: I got the first part but now it's not reading the next part as what I want to put into the "foo" file with cat

Comment: [rbailey@localhost ~]$ bash Project3.sh
    Project3.sh: line 2: Perl:PHP:C++:Python:COBOL:Ruby:Rails: command     not found

Comment: Try `echo "Perl:PHP:C++:Python:COBOL:Ruby:Rails" > File`

Answer (score 0):

I'd write this as a comment, but I need the formatting:

You're looking for a "[here-document](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents)"

```
cat >File <<END_OF_DATA
Perl:PHP:C++:Python:COBOL:Ruby:Rails 
END_OF_DATA
```

@kojiro shows you how to read the file into colon-separated words.

Answer (score 0):

You might try

**`cat File | tr ':' '\n'`**

If you need to 'process' the items then something like:

**`for MYVAR in $(cat File | tr ':' '\n') ; do echo ${MYVAR} ; done`**

:)
Dale